# Does MaxPooling reduce overfitting?

Tags: conv-neural-network, batch-normalization, dropout, max-pooling

I have trained the following CNN model with a smaller data set, therefore it does overfitting:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(28,28,1), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model has a lot of trainable parameters (more than 3 million, that's why I wonder if I should reduce the number of parameters with additional MaxPooling like follows?

Conv - BN - Act - MaxPooling - Conv - BN - Act - MaxPooling - Dropout - Flatten

or with an additional MaxPooling and Dropout like follows?

> Conv - BN - Act - MaxPooling - Dropout - Conv - BN - Act - MaxPooling
>   - Dropout - Flatten

I am trying to understand the full sense of MaxPooling and whether it can help against overfitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overfitting can happen when your dataset is not large enough to accomodate your number of features.
Max pooling uses a max operation to pool sets of features, leaving you with a smaller number of them.
Therefore, max-pooling *should* logically reduce overfit.

Drop-out reduces reliance on any single feature by ensuring that feature is not always available, forcing the model to look for different potential hints, rather than just sticking with one -- which would easily allow the model to overfit on any apparently good hint.
Therefore, this also should help reduce overfit.

Comment: That means do you think my second suggestion is better than the first?

Comment: @CodeNow yes, it should be! By all means try it out though!

Answer (score -1):

You Should **NOT** Use Max-pooling in order to reduce overfitting, although it has a small effect on that, **BUT** this small effect is not enough because you are applying Max-Pooling after the convolutional operations, which means that the features are already trained in this layer and since max-pooling is used to **reduce the hight and width of the output**, this will make the features in the next layer has less convolutional operations to learn from, which means a **LITTLE EFFECT** on the overfitting problem, that won't solve it.
Actually it's not recommended at all using Pooling for this kind of problems, and here are some tips:

1. Reduce the number of your parameters because it's very hard(not impossible) to find enough data to train 3 millions parameters without overfitting.
2. Use regularization techniques like Drop-out which is very effective by the way, or L2-regularization,..etc.
3. 3.DONT use max pooling for the purpose of reducing overfitting because it's is used to reduce the rapresentation and to make the
   network a bit more robust to some features, further more using it so
   much will make the network more and more robust to a some kind of
   featuers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Would it also be good to use padding='valid' instead of padding='same'? Would it be better to omit batch normalization?